# When to use a deep clone of an object reference? or How often?

Tags: c#, oop, object, reference, deep-copy

I know what is `deep copy`, `shallow copy`, and `how to deep copy` etc, but my major doubt is **When to deep copy an object reference? or How often?**

**Scenario 1 :**
Consider a code, for full code please see http://pastebin.com/WEgeBFNb

```
class Box{
        Position pos;
        Box(Position p){ 
           pos = p;      
        }
        Position getPosition(){
          return pos;
        }
   }
```

And a `main()` like:

```
public class Sample{
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Position pos = new Position(3,5);
        Box box = new Box(pos);     
        pos.setX(5);
        System.out.println( box.getPosition().getX()); 
            // Will print 5, but I want Box to retain its value
      }
```

I have achieved the above requirement by:

```
 Box(Position p){ 
           pos = new Position(p);     // Deep cloning 
        }
```

Then I must have a copy constructor in `Position` too, like:

```
Position(Position p){
     x  = p.x;
     y  = p.y;
   }
```

But my question is: **When to use deep cloning?**

**Scenario 2:**
For example, Consider a c# code.

`List<Accounts> = Mysession.getAllAccounts();`. Here, I expect the change in returned object must not reflect in session object. (This case is not only in C#, but in generally any `oop` language)
**So, If I starts deep cloning, then, it's not a easy task, because it goes up to 5 levels deeper objects, with has-a relationship**

Once again, I know to get exact 100% I must deep clone. Agree.

1. **What is more common**? Returning copy of reference or objects?
2. I heard that, deep cloning is a cumbersome process and one must avoid it. so **how often one could  deep - clone?**
3. Could you give some example scenarios (code not needed).
4. While initialization like above `box`  example, one must use cloning `pos = new Position(p)`? or normal assigning `pos = p`?

Comment: if your value objects contains only System.ValueType as fields you can use struct instead of class.so in that case you can simply use pos=p instead of  pos = new Position(p).

Comment: @Frank59 Consider another class which has `has-a` relationship of another objects. say ` new Room(myroom)` here `Room`  contains an `Box`. In this case., In `Room` Constructor I must do like, `this.box = new Box(room.getBox());` [Deep cloning] or simply `this.box = room.getBox()` [reference copying]?

Comment: if you use structs (Box is struct) and ValueTypes(Box fields are value types and structs ) only than you can use neBox=oldBox; (automatically deep copy), but if you have Box as class or have references into Box fields you need to implement deeep copy algorithm. read more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose in object-oriented programming must be that an object gurantees that it is in a leagal state at any time.

Thus when you return an object's reference you should think about:

1. Is the returned object immutable?
2. Does the current object that returns the reference (main object) has values that depend on the returned object? (derived or cached values)

You can react to the answers of these questions in the following ways:

**The returned reference is an immutable object (String, BigDecimal, etc.)**

1. no action required

**The returned reference is a muttable object (array, Date, etc.), but the main object has NO derived values (e.g. only decorates it)**

1. no action required

**The returned reference is a muttable object (array, Date, etc.) and the main object has derived values**

1. Make a copy of the object before you return it. This is applicable if an copy is easy to make and if it is not memory or time consuming (Depends on your non-functional requirements).
2. Return an unmodifiable reference to the original object (like Collections.unmodifiable... does).
3. Return a proxy that detects access to the returned object and that informs the main object about these changes so that the main object can recalculate the derived values and it will not be in an inconsistent state.

Ask yourself the same questions when you get an object reference. Through a constructor or method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking in terms of "deep" or "shallow" cloning, instead think in terms of what each encapsulated object reference represents.  Suppose field `Foo` of some class instance `George` holds a reference of type `IList<String>`.  Such a field could represent at least five different things:

- A reference to an instance of an immutable type, held for the purpose of encapsulating the strings contained therein.
- A reference to an object instance whose type could be mutable, but which will never be exposed to anything that might mutate it, held for the purpose of encapsulating the strings contained therein.
- The only reference that will ever exist anywhere in the universe, outside the call stack of George's methods, to a mutable list which George is using to encapsulate its state.
- A reference to a list whose contents may change, which form part of the mutable state of *some other object*.  The field isn't used to encapsulate the *content* of the list, but rather its *identity*.
- A reference to a list whose contents may change, whose contents are considered to be part of George's state, and to which outside persistent references exist.

If `Foo` is of the first two types, a proper copy of George may have its `Foo` refer either to the same list as `George.Foo`, a newly-constructed list which will always hold the same contents, or any other list which will always hold the same contents.  If it's of the third type, a proper copy of George must have its `Foo` refer to a new list which is preloaded with copies of the items in `George.Foo`.  If it's of the fourth type, a proper copy must have its `Foo` refer to the *same object* as `George.Foo` and *not* refer to a copy.  If it's of the fifth type, `George` cannot be cloned in isolation.

If the list items were of a mutable type (instead of `String`), one would have to determine which of the five purposes applied to the items contained in the list, and treat each list item as one would treat a field.  Note that for a type to be logically immutable, any references contained therein must be shareable.  If proper behavior of an object would require that something to which it holds a reference not be the target of any other reference, that would imply that only one reference should exist to the object holding the reference.